# Android tabs custom view

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view, android-tabs

I am adding tabs to my app with this code:

```
ActionBar.Tab tab1=actionBar.newTab();
tab1.setTabListener(this);
tab1.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_style);
TextView txt1 = (TextView)tab1.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.tabtext);
txt1.setText(R.string.tab_1);
actionBar.addTab(tab1);
```

And this is the tab_style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This is the main layout of the application -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_basic_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white" 
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tabtext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textSize="20dp"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to change tab background,but result:

[image]

How can I fix it ? Customview is not centering.

Comment: add `android:paddingBottom="0dip"` to relativelayout

Comment: Not worked.Still same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**action bar tabs are deprecated in the "L" Developer Preview.**

the black area is background of `actionBar tabBar`.you must style `actionBarTabBarStyle` and set the background of it. look at this link:

http://blog.alwold.com/2013/08/28/styling-tabs-in-the-android-action-bar/

or you can use other library like :

[PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

or if you want to have a google one you can try:

[SlidingTabsBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic)

Comment: You mean I have to change my tab system ?

Comment: I think you had better do it!

Comment: yes, you can also use `fragmentTabHost` or classic `TabHost` and set custom view for the `tabs`.

Comment: For me change action bar color,tab background and indicators is enough.

Comment: so use `PagerSlidingTabStrip`

Answer (score 0):

try margins as per your requirement in your textview it will help

Comment: try this link it will help http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Comment: I am already using this code.I followed this tutorial.But there is no information about background color of tab.